# How git-merge and git-rebase behave with a topic branch forked off of another topic branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging, git-rebase

Let us suppose the repository looks like this:

```
            master
               |
A--B--C--K--L--M
       \
        E-F-G
            |\
            | H-I-J
          topicA  |
                topicB
```

What would `git merge topicB` do when in `master`? Would it apply commits `H`, `I`, and `J` only? or all the commits from the initial fork point of `topicA`?

What would `git rebase master topicA` do? Would it lead to this:

```
            master
               |
A--B--C--K--L--M
                \
                 E'-F'-G'
                       |\
                       | H'-I'-J'
                     topicA    |
                             topicB
```

or something more like this?

```
            master
               |
A--B--C--K--L--M
       \        \
        \        E'-F'-G'
         \             |
          \          topicA
           \          
            E-F-G-H-I-J
                      |
                    topicB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from resolving branch names to commit IDs, neither merge nor rebase care about where any branch labels point.  They look only at the commit graph.

#### merge

The way `git merge` works is a little easier to understand, I think.  Except for saving away a branch name for the default merge commit message, `git merge` just uses `git rev-parse` to find commit IDs.

For your first question, given `git merge topicB` while on branch `master`, git finds three commit IDs:

- `HEAD` resolves to commit `M` (the tip-most commit on branch `master`; this is also the commit ID you see if you run `git rev-parse HEAD`).
- `topicB` resolves to commit `J` (the tip-most commit on branch `topicB`; this is also the commit ID you see if you run `git rev-parse topicB`).
- The merge base of these two commits, as determined (solely) by the commit graph.  In this case, that is commit `C`.

Having found the merge base, git then runs two `git diff`s: one between the merge-base and `HEAD` commits (to see what "your branch" did), and one between the merge-base and `topicB` commits (to see what "their branch" did).  It combines the two sets of changes, and if there are no conflicts (or if it can resolve them via `git rerere`), makes a new commit whose two parents are—in this order—the current `HEAD` commit, and the `topicB` commit.  Making the new commit updates the current branch as usual, so that `HEAD` now points to the new commit (or more precisely, `HEAD` still points to `master`, and `master` points to the new commit).

This question:

> Would it apply commits H, I, and J only? or all the commits from the initial fork point of topicA?

implies a fundamental misunderstanding of git's merge algorithm: git doesn't look at *any* of the intermediate commits.  It looks only at the three commits identified here: `M`, `J`, and `C` in this case.  Git can "cheat" like this because each commit is fully stand-alone in terms of that commit's source tree contents.

#### rebase

Rebase is more complicated (and you have it right in your second guess above, but let's run through it anyway).

It still uses the same "resolve branch names to IDs via `git rev-parse`" trick, but it uses the more complicated `git rev-list` variant.  What `git rev-list` does is compute set operations on the commit graph (again ignoring any labels once it's actually gotten into the graph itself).

Given `git rebase master topicA`, we (well, *I* anyway :-) ) first have to check [the `rebase` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html), where we find that `master` is treated as the *<upstream>* argument and `topicA` is treated as the *<branch>* argument, and that all it does with that last argument is run `git checkout <branch>` first, then proceed as if you had not supplied it.  So mentally we can just assume you started by doing `git checkout topicA`, then run `git rebase master`.  The *<upstream>* argument is `master` and `HEAD` refers to branch `topicA` so it identifies commit `G`.

In the old days, before `git rebase` had `--fork-point`, it was easier to be certain what happens next.  Today, as per the documentation, you must determine whether `--fork-point` is enabled.  Because you *did* give an actual *<upstream>* argument, it's disabled by default: it's only enabled if you gave `--fork-point` on the command line; you didn't;, and therefore we need not delve into the mysteries of `--fork-point` (whew, yay! :-) ).  So, what happens here is that rebase essentially runs `git rev-list master..HEAD` to get the list of commits to copy.  This lists commits `E`, `F`, and `G`, as those are the commits in the set reachable by `HEAD` but not by `master`.

The rebase process then detaches `HEAD` at the commit given by the `--onto` argument if any (there wasn't any), or to the commit given by the *<upstream>* argument.  That was `master` so this is commit `M`.  From here, rebase essentially just cherry-picks each of the commits it found earlier, which gives you commits `E'`, `F'`, and `G'`.  If all this works properly, git's last step for the rebase is to point the originally-current branch (`topicA`, again) to the last commit, `G'`.  No other label changes, so you get the final graph you drew.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I was afraid I'd get a very shallow or partial answer, and the question will go unanswered but I honestly couldn't

 ask for a better one. I hope this one helps other users here as well, because the git documentation wasn't clear enough for me on that topic.

Comment: What rebase operation(s) would lead to the first graph (i.e topic and derived topic branches being based off of master's tip, instead of leaving topicB where it is)?

Comment: To address the second comment, there isn't any built-in "multi-rebase".  I wrote a python script to do the job for myself but I haven't tested it well enough to put it up anywhere.